# Magento 2.4.6 : Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, installation, magento2.4.6, opensearch

I'm trying to install Magento open source for the first time.
I have gone through most of the process except the last part.
When I try to run:
`php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento2 --db-user=root --db-password= --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=admin@admin.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1`
or :

```
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento2 \
--db-user=root \
--db-password= \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1 \
--search-engine=opensearch \
--opensearch-host=os-host.example.com \
--opensearch-port=9200 \
--opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
--opensearch-timeout=15
```

from the Magento documentation, I get the following error:

```
In SearchConfig.php line 81:

  Could not validate a connection to the OpenSearch. No alive nodes found in your cluster
```

I tried checking the source of the issue by testing OpenSearch, and sent couple of requests and it is working:

`curl.exe -X GET http://localhost:9200`

returned:

> {
> "name" : "DESKTOP-HD81RFN",
> "cluster_name" : "opensearch",
> "cluster_uuid" : "HwWhh2IyRIWI_C952vAbkg",
> "version" : {
> "distribution" : "opensearch",
> "number" : "2.6.0",
> "build_type" : "zip",
> "build_hash" : "7203a5af21a8a009aece1474446b437a3c674db6",
> "build_date" : "2023-02-24T19:18:51.456570800Z",
> "build_snapshot" : false,
> "lucene_version" : "9.5.0",
> "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "7.10.0",
> "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "7.0.0"
> },
> "tagline" : "The OpenSearch Project: [https://opensearch.org/"](https://opensearch.org/%22)
> }

same result when I check `http://localhost:9200/` on my browser.

Another test I did was sending:`netstat -ano | find "9200"`  to see if OpenSearch is listening to the requests on the port, and it is:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9200           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7148
TCP    [::]:9200              [::]:0                 LISTENING       7148
TCP    [::1]:9200             [::1]:64743            ESTABLISHED     7148
TCP    [::1]:64743            [::1]:9200             ESTABLISHED     2125
```

Now I don't know the possible source of the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Replace `--search-engine=opensearch` with `--search-engine= elasticsearch7`, it will solve your issue.

It is intended to bypass the Magento installation/upgrade process, you can change the configuration for the search engine back to OpenSearch afterward by running:

```
bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'opensearch'
```

This is an installation/upgrade issue in Magento 2.4.6, see https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37236

Comment: the search engine im using is not elasticsearch7 but rather opensearch, thats why i made it opensearch.
do i uninstall opensearch and switch to elasticsearch?

Comment: No, you don't need. Just use that modification during setup/upgrade Magento, you can switch it back to opensearch after that by running: `bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'opensearch'`

Comment: thanks a lot, worked for me, have other issues now, but it stopped on this one

Comment: @AdnaneRbt You're welcome. Could you confirm which Magento version you are installing?

Comment: yes, it's : "version": "2.4.6"
can update aswell with the other issues i had until it worked and the solutions i found if you want

Comment: @AdnaneRbt I got it, thanks. I asked this because the issue happened on Magento 2.4.6 but you tagged Magento version 2.3.

Answer (score 11):

By default OpenSearch uses SSL, but magento doesn't use it. So it needs to disable SSL plugin in OpenSearch for successful magento installation:

```
sudo nano /etc/opensearch/opensearch.yml
```

And add this to the end of yml file:

```
plugins.security.disabled: true
```

I get it from [there.](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37236#issuecomment-1616069833)

Comment: You also need to un-commet the line: `http.port: 9200`, for opensearch to listen to an insecure port

Comment: The comment from Dallas is correct. You need to do this as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing --opensearch-host=os-host.example.com 
to --opensearch-host=localhost \

HTH, Tom

Comment: i tried with your suggestion and it returned
```  No arguments expected for "setup:install" command, got "\--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee" ```

Comment: Please post your complete setup:install command with all the parameters.
The parameter "opensearch-host" should be set to localhost.

Comment: ```php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \--db-host=localhost \--db-name=magento2 \--db-user=root \--db-password= \--admin-firstname=admin \--admin-lastname=admin \--admin-email=admin@admin.com \--admin-user=admin \--admin-password=admin123 \--language=en_US \--currency=USD \--timezone=America/Chicago \--use-rewrites=1 \--search-engine=opensearch \--opensearch-host=localhost \--opensearch-port=9200 \--opensearch-index-prefix=magento2 \--opensearch-timeout=15 
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is possibly caused by incorrect configuration of opensearch in core_config_data.
Try running the following commands in your SQL console:

```
update core_config_data set value = "opensearch" where path = "catalog/search/opensearch_server_hostname";

update core_config_data set value = "opensearch" where path = "catalog/search/engine";

update core_config_data set value = "9200" where path = "catalog/search/opensearch_server_port";
```

Comment: Using `opensearch` as hostname did the trick for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

From https://opensearch.org/docs/1.1/security-plugin/configuration/disable/

> A more permanent option is to remove the security plugin entirely:
>
> - Delete the plugins/opensearch-security folder on all nodes.
> - Delete all plugins.security.* configuration entries from opensearch.yml.

Note: `plugins.security.disabled: true` is still needed in the `opensearch.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the similar issue and i have found that Opensearch was working but still it keep displaying "No alive nodes found in your cluster" After spending hours i was able to figure out that security issue Our local website was on http and running the cmd
curl http://localhost:9200
returned
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

On the other side curl https://localhost:9200 is returning the required result

**Solution**
You need to configure the SSL locally to resolve this issue